# WP can send test mail, Contact Form 7 can't

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

As mentioned in the title, I have a WP site, I use WP-SMTP and can send test mails perfectly. However Contact Form 7 or any other contact form plugin can't send any mails. What would you suggest?

**Edit:** I should mention, I can send test mails via SMTP only with no encryption. When I select SSL or TLS encryption, it also fails.

Comment: What PHP mailing function does CF7 use? It might be bypassing WP-SMTP.

Comment: @ojrask I didn't examine the codes, sorry I don't know.

Comment: If there's a `wpmail` function call there somewhere then it should be working with WP-SMTP I presume.

Comment: @ojrask it uses `WPCF7_Mail::send` as i can see, and it refers to `wp_mail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the cause of the problem was the plugin. Although, it is a known and popular plugin, which works perfectly for many users, in my site it doesn't work. I changed to `Fast Secure Contact Form` and problem solved.